# Can't install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome

Yesterday I freshly installed Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal) 32bit on my laptop but couldn't install Google Chrome on it. Google Chrome was working fine with my previous Ubuntu 10.04. While I tried to install the package I downloaded from Google Chrome site,

```
$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

It shows the following error-

```
Selecting previously deselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 135527 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (from google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libnspr4-0d (>= 4.7.1); however:
  Package libnspr4-0d is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libnss3-1d (>= 3.12.3); however:
  Package libnss3-1d is not installed.
dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.en_US.utf8.cache...
Processing triggers for python-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

When I tried to install libnss3-1d manually, it returns broken package error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss3-1d : Depends: libnss3 (= 3.12.9~b2-0ubuntu1) but 3.12.9+ckbi-1.82-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Any help?

Comment: have you tried downloading from ubuntu software center?

Comment: ubuntu software center chromium, the open source version. I wanted to use the Google release version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error and tried different things. Also tried installing libnss3-1d.

Finally succeeded when I installed `libnspr4-0d`

```
sudo apt-get install libnspr4-0d
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. I tried this before but it was failing because my repo list (bd.ubuntu.com) wasn't updated. Later I pointed to US server and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

That rather obtuse answer is how `dpkg` announces a dependency conflict. ("X won't be installed because it requires Y which can't be installed at the same time as Z and Z is required by something you already have")

My best guess is that you're trying to install a Chrome package for a different version of Ubuntu. (Which doesn't work. `.deb`s are very specific about their dependencies)

Can you elaborate on why you feel Chromium isn't a suitable alternative to Chrome?

Comment: Google provides a single .deb file. So I couldn't find any alternative.

Comment: I am opted to use Google chrome over chromium because Google release is suppose to be more stable and tested

Comment: Yeah. Google really tries to oversimplify their Linux offerings to the point that the .deb will handle adding their repo without asking you (to replicate the Windows version's "Don't ask. Just silently upgrade." behaviour as closely as possible). As for stability, I haven't found it to be a problem. In fact, on Gentoo, if anything, Chromium is **more** stable because the ebuild which compiles it is written by people who know about potential problem points in Gentoo.

Comment: Once I used to use chromium when Chrome wasn't officially released for Linux. But that crashes very often. Surely Google doesn't care as much as their Windows and Mac users, but when I installed Chrome after all these the problems are gone. Since then I have been using Chrome.