# Google chrome dependency error - libnss3

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-12.04, administrator

I downloaded the .deb file from Google chrome website. Then started installing. But suddenly the software center shows a `dependency not satisfied` error. Some thing like given below.

`Dependency not satisfiable:libnss3 (>=3.14.3)`

Then I have tried all these.

- http://www.webupd8.org/2009/09/dependency-is-not-satisfiable-libnss3.html
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/220960/cannot-install-google-chrome-how-do-i-fix-it
- [Can't install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 11.04](https://superuser.com/questions/280943/cant-install-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-11-04)

But not yet solved..Still the same issue.

Please give an advice on this.

Comment: If none of those work, how did they fail? And what did you actually attempt?

Comment: I really don't know what is the issue here. Still it shows the same in Software Center. Whenever I try to install libnss3 by `sudo apt-get install libnss3` it says `libnss3 is already the newest version`. What could be the issue. I think, the installed version is not greater than 3.14.3. If that is the case how can I upgrade to the lateset version. Is there any version compatibility issue with Ubuntu OS, like Ubuntu 12.04 can install libnss3 version less than 3.14.3!!

Comment: I'm just guessing: have you tried to run ```sudo apt-get install libnss3-dev```?

Comment: Dear Dairo, Still it shows the same issue :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it solved from this link
http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/libnss3/download.

- As it says added this line `deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main` at the end of `/etc/apt/sources.list`
- sudo apt-get update
- This may cause gpg key error.
- `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 8BAF9A6F`. (Refer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey).
- Again run `sudo apt-get update` if gpg error had occured.
- `sudo apt-get install libnss3`.

This installed me with latest libnss3 and it solved issue with installing google-chrome.